# html pre tag formatting not displaying properly in browsers

Tags: html, pre

so i started learning html and i've come upon this tag 
it's supposed to reserve spaces/new lines
and here is an image of the code
https://prnt.sc/twqf1k

but whenever i open it up in the browser it shows up like this
https://prnt.sc/twqf8f

now i know that i could drag the code a little backwards but i write it this way so it's a "clean code"
and i tried using qoutes but it didn't work and i would really like to find a way around it

thanks in advance

Comment: hello and welcome to stackoverflow. In order to catch attention and probably the right answer to your interogation i recommend you to have look on [how to ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I can't see on your post any question or runnable example of code.

Answer (score 0):

after some research i finally found the answer to my question
and it is to write the tag like this.

```
<pre style="white-space: pre-line;">
        now the pre tag doesn't work like This
        as it will preserve the extra     spaces
        and the new lines created
        which helps when you want to write a peom
        or any similar text"
    </pre>
```

thanks for reading
and sorry for not finding this earlier